# Extjs is sharing arrays between simple classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs

I have 2 classes extending from base class.
Class1 extends BaseClass
Class2 extends BaseClass
I create instance of 1 and 2.
When I alerting the array content of Class2, I get also the content of array one.

http://jsfiddle.net/k3emY/2/

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
   var c1 = Ext.create('Child1Class');    
   var c2 = Ext.create('Child2Class');
   alert(c2.someArray.join());  
   //actual result: "BaseClass text ,Class1 text,Class2 text"
   //expected :"BaseClass text ,Class2 text"
});


Ext.define('BaseClass', {
    someArray: ["BaseClass text "],
});

Ext.define('Child1Class', {
    extend : 'BaseClass',
    constructor : function(){
        this.someArray[this.someArray.length] = "Class1 text";
    }
});

Ext.define('Child2Class', {
    extend : 'BaseClass',
    constructor : function(){
        this.someArray[this.someArray.length] = "Class2 text";
    }
});
```

Why Class1 participating in this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someArray` is a property of the `BaseClass`'s prototype. Prototype's properties are shared between subclasses and instances. To avoid this result, declare the array from a constructor. Consider the following scenario which is a simplified version of yours :

```
function Class() {}
Class.prototype.array = [];

var c1 = new Class();
var c2 = new Class();
c1.array.push('a');
c2.array; // ["a"]
```

Actually, this is quite close to this :

```
var array = [];
var c1 = { array: array };
var c2 = { array: array };
c1.array === c2.array; // true
```

Now, let's use the constructor :

```
function Class() {
    this.array = [];
}

var c1 = new Class();
var c2 = new Class();
c1.array.push('a');
c2.array; // []
```

This scenario can be simplified as well :

```
var c1 = { array: [] };
var c2 = { array: [] };
c1.array === c2.array; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's the same array. you can create a new array for each instance like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpH5g/1/):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var c1 = Ext.create('Child1Class');
    var c2 = Ext.create('Child2Class');

    alert(c2.someArray.join());
});

Ext.define('BaseClass', {
    constructor: function (config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        Ext.apply(this, {
            someArray: ["BaseClass text "],
        });
    }
});

Ext.define('Child1Class', {
    extend: 'BaseClass',
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.someArray[this.someArray.length] = "Class1 text";
    }
});

Ext.define('Child2Class', {
    extend: 'BaseClass',
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.someArray[this.someArray.length] = "Class2 text";
    }
});
```